# Extract distinct values

Tags: distinct, google-bigquery

I have a big table of emails which has many emails repeated. I want to extract DISTINCT emails from it. Can't do it due to unavailability of DISTINCT and limitation of GROUP EACH BY or TOP function (Errors:Resources exceeded during query execution.).

Comment: GROUP EACH BY should work. Can you give a job id of a job that hit a resources exceeded error?

Comment: @Jatin: We end up splitting table and then did GROUP EACH BY to get disticts

Comment: @JordanTigani: job_nOVZrMeIaCn5FBPsN6JvRmWGbkw

Comment: Hey Jordan, were you able to look into this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Investigating. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

A simple query with `GROUP BY` (without aggregate functions) should be enough:

```
SELECT email
FROM YouTableWithDuplicateEMails  
GROUP BY email
```